# Using Ipinfo.io in Javascript

Tags: javascript, get, geolocation, httprequest

Okay, so, I'm trying to pull the correct region and city from Ipo.io but it isn't working. When ran locally it's giving me one location, which is wrong, and when deployed it also gives me a location but it's also wrong.

**What I'm Trying To Do:** pull the correct locations when user clicks a button.

The html is fine, so no need to add it. The js file where the request is looks like so (didn't include the whole file, just the relevant parts).

showMe is a modal that pops up once a user is scrolling the screen. Everything works fine the location is just wrong. I looked at the docs and it doesn't say anything about Javascript, so I'm writing to you guys in hopes that this tool actually works with Javascript.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
$('#showMe').click(() => {
    $('#time-text').empty();
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io?token=insert-token", function (response) {
        $('#time-text').append(response.region);
    }, "jsonp")
});
```

also, just to be clear, i've also tried this - as given in their documentation, but it throws an error.

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        $('#time-text').append(response.region);
    }, "jsonp")
```

The error I am receiving for the last implemention is:

```
jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 GET https://ipinfo.io/?callback=jQuery34105473588412770183_1578083636662&_=1578083636663 net::ERR_ABORTED 429
```

For the first implementation, there is no error - just wrong location.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: @Light Sorry, just updated the question. The second implementation throws an error while the first implementation just gives the wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a [429 Error](https://httpstatuses.com/429), which means you've hit the request limit for the Day / Month (Depends)

Here is the relevant part of the the [Docs](https://ipinfo.io/developers#rate-limits) discussing the Rate Limits

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and surely it is throwing a 429 error. The problem is, when I go to my dashboard in Ipo.info - it's stating I have 50k requests this month of which I've only used 11. So it isn't making sense to me why I would get that error.

Comment: and also, it doesn't give me that error when I do the first implementation - just the wrong location.

Comment: It's probably directing to the ISP's datacenter then; Failing that, I'll delete this answer as it wasn't valid

Comment: @DreJackson Did you figure out what the location issue was?

Comment: nah, but I have a rough idea of what could be the problem. After doing research it seems that location by IP is highly inaccurate. In order to get accurate details of location I'd need to use latitude and longitude, then I'd be able to use something like this to get the state where the user is. Can't do that though without explicitly asking for permission - which I don't want to do. So, I just scratched the idea completely. Thanks for your help though @Light

Comment: No worries - Sorry I couldn't help more

Comment: all good, thanks for the insight on 429 error. Now whenever I see it (hopefully never, ha) I can quickly identify the problem. @Light